# Using a regular expression with CORS

Tags: regex, apache, cors

I am trying to use a regular expression with cors. I have read many times that this is not possible that cors is all (*) or exact domains. [Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard subdomains, ports and protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols) . However this seems to contradict :http://www.cameronstokes.com/2010/12/26/cross-origin-resource-sharing-and-apache-httpd/. Could somebody clarify and if using a regular expression is possible provide a simple example as I have tried to implement the link above but with no success.

The regular expression is wish to use is

```
    ^http\://\blocal-.*\b\.testing-test:10005$
```

I have checked my regex and it matches the generated URLs. 
I have added SetEnvIF and Header set lines as suggested to my apache2.conf (is this correct?) as follows

```
    SetEnvIf Origin "^http\://\blocal-.*\b\.mycompany-it:10005$" 

    AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0 Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %

    {AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
```

I am lost as to what to do next.It doesn't work
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't include regexp in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  All of this is covered in the question you linked to.  You can certainly write your own code that generates the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header programmatically, as discussed in the articled you linked to.  If you need help implementing this, show us some attempts you have made to implement the logic described in the article, and why/how they have failed.

Answer (score 5):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin Headers can only be a wildcard '*' or an exact url. One way to do this is to first get the value of the Origin header from the request (this varies from server to server, but one sample might look like: `request.headers['Origin']`).

Then do a regex check with the value of the request Origin. If the request's origin passes the check with the allowed regex expression, then you can simply set the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the value of the request's Origin (sample: `response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.headers['Origin']`). In this way, you aren't violating the rule of the access control being a strict url, but also allowing the server to accept multiple different allowed origins.

Comment: It looks like you are writing JavaScript for ExpressJS on NodeJS. The question is asking about Apache configuration directives.