# ajax CORS issue of with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin regexp value

Tags: json, ajax, regex, cors, cross-domain

Hy,

I've this error when I do a request ajax to another domain:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://rec.something.fr/services/data.
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value '*.something.fr'.
Origin 'http://local.something.fr' is therefore not allowed access
```

I don't understand if the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header can use or not a regexp expression. Some sources said it can, other said it cannot.

The big issue is that it's another society who is in charge of the http://rec.something.fr. Before I call them, I want to be sure that the issue is on their server, and not that's something on my code who is missing.

my code:(Origin = http://local.something.fr)

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://rec.something.fr/services/data",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json" })
```

the content of the called Services is a Json:

```
[{data:myData}]
```

If I use the CORS chrome plugin who catch the response and replace 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.something.fr
by
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, It will work.

I cannot use JSONP because this would require updating the rec.something.fr server

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` values can’t be regular expressions or any other kind of pattern. They must either exactly match the request `Origin` header, or be `null`, or be a single literal `*`.

See also [the accepted answer to the question *Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard subdomains, ports and protocols*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14006226/441757) and the first comment for the question [*Using a regular expression with CORS*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439340/using-a-regular-expression-with-cors).

So there’s no fix you can make on your side to work around this. The `http://rec.something.fr` maintainers just need to fix the broken `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header they’re sending.

> I don't understand if the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header can use
>   or not a regexp expression. Some sources said it can, other said it
>   cannot.

It definitely cannot. The current authoritative source for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` valid syntax is the ABNF production for it in the [“HTTP new-header syntax” section of the Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-new-header-syntax):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin      = origin-or-null / "*"
```

For a good secondary source, see the [“Handling a simple request” section of the *Using CORS* article at HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-handling-a-simple-request), which states it this way:

> The value of the header can either echo the Origin request header, or be a `'*'` to allow requests from any origin.

So if you want to try to help the `http://rec.something.fr` maintainers correct their server config, you can suggest to them that they should change the code in their server logic to do the following:

- for requests from origins matching `*.something.fr`, send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` back with a value that’s exactly the same as the value of the request `Origin` header
- otherwise, for requests from origins that do not match `*.something.fr`, then just don’t send back `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` at all

Comment: Thank you very much,  do you know how I can do to allow two diferent Origin (http://local.something.fr and http://local2.something.fr') without using * ?

Comment: To allow two different origins `local.something.fr` and `local2.something.fr`, something like (pseudocode) `if (origin == "local.something.fr" or origin == "local2.something.fr") { header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = origin }`. The real code that would be needed depends on what the actual web-server software is and what mechanisms it provides for setting headers conditionally.