# Cors Filter - Allow all sub domains

Tags: java, spring, cross-domain, cors

I would like my CorsFilter to do the following:

```
// populating the header required for CORS
response.addHeader(
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
           "https://*.myDomain.com");
```

The whole idea is to allow the following domains to make a request:
sub1.myDomain.com,
sub2.myDomain.com,
sub3.myDomain.com
....
sub100.myDomain.com

This didn't work for me. How can I achieve this? Iv'e tried:

```
response.addHeader(
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
           "*.myDomain.com");
```

as well with no success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols

Comment: For Spring Boot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53611336/2590616

Comment: For the scroll-impaired, [jasiek.miko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147737/cors-filter-allow-all-sub-domains/65142107#65142107)'s answer is more useful that the current top voted answer.

Answer (score 19):

This use case is now directly supported by [CorsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#setAllowedOriginPatterns-java.util.List-).

Modifying the [docs example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.2/reference/html5/#cors) to match your question, this could be:

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("https://*.myDomain.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

It's worth noting that wildcards like this are still **not** part of the CORS standard. Instead, this is a Spring mechansim for returning CORS-compliant header values *based* on your pattern.

E.g. if you now make a call from `Origin=https://subdomain.myDomain.com` the response will contain the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=https://subdomain.myDomain.com`.

Comment: Good that Spring added setAllowedOriginPatterns with 5.3 spring-web version. Nice instead of writing own CorsConfiguraiton. Thanks for pointer :-)

Answer (score 16):

I am having the similar question and the answer is Yes.

Here is my solution ( Handling Access-Control-Allow-Origin based on the origin header)

**1. Parse host from the 'origin' header**

```
    // origin
    String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");

    URL originUrl = null;
    try {
        originUrl = new URL(origin);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    }

    // originUrl.getHost() -> Return the host need to be verified
```

**2. Check originUrl.getHost()**

```
    // Allow myDomain.com
    // Or anySubDomain.myDomain.com
    // Or subSub.anySubDomain.myDomain.com

    // hostAllowedPattern 
    Pattern hostAllowedPattern = Pattern.compile("(.+\\.)*myDomain\\.com", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    // Allow host?
    if (hostAllowedPattern.matcher(originUrl.getHost()).matches()) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);

    } else {
        // Throw 403 status OR send default allow
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://my_domain.com");
    }
```

**3. Result:**

```
    // If 'origin': https://sub1.myDomain.com  --> Matched
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sub1.myDomain.com

    // If 'origin': https://sub2.myDomain.com   --> Matched
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sub2.myDomain.com

    // If 'origin': https://notAllowDomain.com   --> Not Matched
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my_domain.com
```

**4. Others:**

```
    You need to verify scheme & port too.
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't, it's either full domain, `null` or all: `*`.

Like spec says:
http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header

Comment: Can't is such a strong word ^^

Answer (score 0):

On Spring Boot, this is what worked for multiple domains.

Reference - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.2/reference/html5/#cors

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${cross-origin-domains:https://example1.com,https://example2.com}")
    private List<String> crossOriginDomains;

    @Value("${cross-origin.paths:/path1/**,/path2/**}")
    private List<String> crossOriginPaths;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(withDefaults())
        .
        //Any other configuration you need
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(this.crossOriginDomains);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        for (String api : this.crossOriginPaths) {
            source.registerCorsConfiguration(api, configuration);
        }
        return source;
    }

}
```

And in `application.properties` or in `Consul`, you can have these configs & values

```
ccc.cross-origin.domains=https://example1.com,https://example3.com
ccc.cross-origin.paths=/path1/**,/path2/**,/path3/**
```