# Add comma separated value into springboot @CrossOrigin origins

Tags: spring-boot, bind, cross-origin-read-blocking, dynamic-values

application.properties

```
my.cross.origin.urls=https://test.com,https://abcd.com
```

my controller method.

```
 @CrossOrigin(origins = "${my.cross.origin.urls}")
@PostMapping(value = RequestMappings.CREATE_USER_V3)
    public @ResponseBody TestResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

}
```

how can I bind 'my.cross.origin.urls' values as an array?

Answer (score 0):

Add URLs like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"https://test.com", "https://abcd.com"})
@PostMapping(value = RequestMappings.CREATE_USER_V3)
public @ResponseBody TestResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

}
```

I hope it will solve your problem
or you can check this post [add multiple cross origin urls in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623211/add-multiple-cross-origin-urls-in-spring-boot)

Comment: is there any possibility to inject values through application properties

Answer (score 0):

use this approach

```
 //In application.properties
 my.cross.origin.urls=https://test.com,https://abcd.com
```

and

```
 @CrossOrigin("${my.cross.origin.urls}")
 @PostMapping(value = RequestMappings.CREATE_USER_V3)
 public @ResponseBody TestResponse(HttpServletRequest request, 
 HttpServletResponse response){

 }
```

let me know if this works there are other approaches also but for the sake of simplicity I think it is better

Comment: already tried this and not working

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the properties to a list with SpEL like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "#{'${my.cross.origin.urls}'.split(',')}")
```

Comment: already tried this and not working

Comment: OK. It looks like the CorsConfiguration does not accept placeholders for the property allowedOrigins. From JavaDoc: "note that such placeholders must be resolved externally." Probably the only way would be to configure them programmatically.