# kendo uploader Cross domain issue in Web.Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-web-api, kendo-upload

i already enable the Cors in my WEB API project ! all other methods inside the API controller  can access from the other project !

but kendo uploader request can not reach to the controller method

```
 $("#files").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                saveUrl: 'http://localhost:23618/API/test/UploadAttachment',

                removeUrl: 'http://localhost:23618/API/test/RemoveAttachment',
                autoUpload: true
            },

            upload: function (e) {
                e.data = { contactID: 5 };
            },

            error: onError

        });
```

error

```
A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:23617' is therefore not allowed access.
```

here is my cors

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: What happens when you set withCredentials to false?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/cross-domain-webapi-sample)

Comment: @Dandy nothing happen

Comment: @SirwanAfifi im asking abt uploader

Comment: Do you still get the same error?

Comment: var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:23617","*","*"); try putting origin domain in the EnableCorsAttribute parameter. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols

Answer (score 11):

Trying it this way worked for me..
http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/upload#configuration-async.withCredentials

```js
$("#files").kendoUpload({
            multiple: false,
            async: {
                withCredentials: false,
                saveUrl: "url",
                autoUpload: true
            },
            success: onSuccess
        });
```