# Web API CORS does not return correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

Trying to understand and debug an issue with a CORS setup on WebAPI 2.
My front-end angular/javascript application communicates with my API at

> http://api.example.com/api/items/GetAll

which **sometimes** returns the following error:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'http://example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Testing the api link on Fiddler returns the following in the headers:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com

Why would this happen and how do I address this situation?

Comment: it's pretty clear, on one side you have `http://example.com` and on the other you have `http://www.example.com` (note the `www`). these are not the same origin.  nor is `api.example.com` which seems like it's more likely what is in one of these changed errors.

Comment: yes but my question is: why is example.com being returned in the header although my API is being called from www.example.com?

Comment: it's impossible for anyone to know why your code is returning an incorrect result without any sort of [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have calls to both types of domain/URL in your client-side code.

Based on that assumption, CORS should be specified for both domains i.e.

```
http://example.com 
http://www.example.com
```

References:

1. https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header
2. [Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard subdomains, ports and protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols)