# Requests to ring-cors enabled site fails

Tags: clojure, cors, middleware, ring

I have two ring sites: `mysite.com` and `api.mysite.com`. `api.mysite.com` has the [`ring-cors`](https://github.com/r0man/ring-cors) middleware enabled:

```
(def app
  (-> (make-handler v1-routes)
      (wrap-defaults api-defaults)
      (wrap-cors :access-control-allow-origin  [#".*"]
                 :access-control-allow-headers ["Content-Type"]
                 :access-control-allow-methods [:get :put :post :delete :options])))
```

When I do a `GET` or `POST` request, the preflight succeeds but the `GET` or `POST` fails with:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://api.site.com/v1/site. (Reason: CORS
>   header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I can see in the debugger that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is included in the `OPTIONS` response but not in the subsequent `GET` or `POST` response.

Any idea what's up? My app is a bit complex and also has `bidi`, `liberator`, and some `hosts` file and `nginx` stuff going on. I think those can be put aside for now and the issue traced to some problem with the middleware or middleware configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can use wildcard on sub-domains. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14006226) for more details. Looks like [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) requires either a domain name or a wildcard, but not both.

You might try adding your domain to see if this fixes the problem, and then go from there.

```
wrap-cors :access-control-allow-origin  [#"http://sitename.com"]
```

Comment: It looks like `ring-cors` matches against given regex and associates the origin to the `access-control-allow-origin` header when matched. So nope, this doesn't appear to be the answer.