# Laravel CORS issue

Tags: php, laravel, cors, middleware

I am calling a login method from subdomain on main domain, and I made a CORS middleware which should take care of it. However it doesn't work as expected.

I want to check if requests came from a specific domain, so I tried doing this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
        return $next($request);

    $originalDomain = config('session.domain');

    $parsedUrl = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $splitDomain = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host'], 2);
    $subdomain = $splitDomain[0];
    $domain = $splitDomain[1];

    $subdomainValid = ($parsedUrl['host'] != $originalDomain) && ($originalDomain == $domain);

    if(!$subdomainValid)
        return $next($request);

    $allowedUrl = $parsedUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $subdomain . '.' . config('session.domain');

    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $allowedUrl)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, x-requested-with, x-csrf-token');
}
```

But the issue I'm having is that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` sometimes doesn't return the value I expect. Shouldn't it return origin of the request?

Comment: **'HTTP_REFERER'
The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.**

Comment: Okay, and the solution?

Comment: use a static url?

Comment: I have 3500 subdomains, from each you can call a login method. How do you propose having a static url :)

Comment: then you need something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990162/1906356

Comment: This works more or less the same way as the regex there (I saw that post before), the issue is getting the right referer so that parsing can take place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually changed referrer to origin and added this part of code which resolves my issue:

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))
        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
    else
        $referrer = request()->url();
```