# Enable CORS Wildcard subdomains with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, cors, azure-functions

Azure Functions allows us to enable CORS and give a specific set of urls that are allowed access. We can also enter the wildcard character (`*`) which allows all domains to have access to the function.

Is there a way to add an entry into the CORS setting to allow all subdomains of a particular domain access to the function rather than explicitly setting each subdomain? We have tried adding an entry such as `http://*.example.com` to see if that would allow the subdomains to get access, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm wondering if there is any other way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols), CORS is all or nothing when it comes to hostnames. You must provide the explicit domain or subdomain. It's part of the overall specification and not Microsoft-specific.

Since you don't have access to the underlying server in Azure Functions, you can't use the proposed RegEx-based header for CORS.

Thus, I'd recommend that you look at using JSONP, if your function output is JSON. It can be as simple as checking for the callback query string parameter and wrapping your output in the callback function. Example in Node.js:

```js
const addCallback = function (context, req) {
  if (req.query && req.query.callback) {
    context.res.body = callback + '(' + JSON.stringify(context.res.body) + ')'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will look into the JSONP implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks to be a bug in the Functions App service.

In Azure Web Apps, the CORS interface accepts subdomain wildcards, and it simply works for any subdomain under that wildcard.

But not in Functions Apps. You need to type the full URL of all subdomains to allow them access.

Or, you can simply allow all request origins by using the '*' entry in CORS interface, and then apply your own CORS logic inside your function code.