# Add all subdomains to CORS azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

In my Azure function, I need to add all subdomains for my `mytestwebsite.com`,

I'm trying `https://*.mytestwebsite.com` but it says:

> CORS origin needs to be of format:
> [HTTP|HTTPS]://[www.]domain.[TLD][:portnumber]. Examples:
> http://example.com, https://example.com:8080

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, the CORS spec is everything or nothing.
It supports only *, null or exact domain.

For reference :
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header

Comment: Can we do it using Code ? I mean check request url ? or add cors in code ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible. More details in the following StackOverflow:

[Enable CORS Wildcard subdomains with Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977435/enable-cors-wildcard-subdomains-with-azure-functions)