# How to identify that my domain has opened the popup window?

Tags: javascript, popup

So have one url like:

`https://subdomain.domain.com/popuppage`

I am opening this in popup window using:

`window.open("https://subdomain.domain.com/popuppage", null, "height=600,width=800")`

Now the same page is opened in new tab after clicking on the link of third party website. The issue is I want to identify that it is being opened by me or third party website. Is there any way to do it?

I have tried by checking `window.opener` property but in both cases I am getting `window.opener` and browser doesn't allows me to access any property of `window.opener` because of CORS policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to access the `window.opener.location.href`. If it works it is the same domain (hence no third party) and if it fails it most likely is not (hence third party).

```js
  window.onload = function(){
    var _CORS = null;

    try{
      window.opener && window.opener.location.href;
      _CORS = false
      //REM: Edit according to comment
      /*
      _CORS = !(
          !window.opener ||
          (window.opener.location.href && window.location.host === window.opener.location.host)
      )
      */
    }
    catch(err){
      _CORS = true
    };

    alert('Third party: ' + _CORS)
  };
```

Put this one in `https://subdomain.domain.com/popuppage` in the `<head>` or however you want to evaluate it further.

Comment: Yes, It works. But there one more issue, I want to validate for the same domain, subdomain doesn't matter. Here I am able to identify for the same origin only. Any idea?

Comment: @Hriday Modi: Isnt that the same unless you explicitly allow CO? Anyway, you may always add an `window.location.host === window.opener.location.host` to the evaluation.

Comment: No, hosts are different but domain are same. So say `subdomain1.domain.com` opens the popup of url `subdomain2.domain.com`. Here also i get exception because it only allows  the same host to access property of parent window.

Comment: @Hriday Modi: So you want to allow CO on same domain but with different subdomains, right?

Comment: Yes, subdomain1 should be able to access parent window of same domain.

Comment: @Hriday Modi: I dont think that is something you can influence in javascript. If at all it sounds more like a server setting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols

Comment: Cool, But your solution solves the problem for different host. Thanks!