# Regex expression addition in cors filter

Tags: cors, tomcat9

I am trying to add a regex to allow request for https://\d+.xyz.com e.g. https://1344.xyz.com in web.xml file on Apache Tomcat 9. I'm adding the below expression in web.xml file:

```
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
      <param-value>https://\d+.xyz.com,http://example.com  <!-- another non regex origin format   --></param-value>
```

It is not working and giving 403 error. I got a solution for this in this answer
[Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard subdomains, ports and protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols/27990162)
but I'm not sure of where exactly do I need to add this code in file.
Could anyone help me on it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for keeping your first post clear, concise, and for including relevant info such as your configuration and intention.

Tomcat's CORS Filter does not support wildcards in the allowed origins list except for the global wildcard (`*`). That parameter must include a list of case-sensitive allowed "Origin" values.

If you would like to enhance this, you can create your own filter extending or duplicating the logic `CorsFilter` but changing this method to accept pattern matches. The method is private, so if you extend the class then you would also need to modify all callers.

See the [Tomcat 9 CORS Filter documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter/Initialisation_parameters) and the CORS Filter [`isOriginAllowed`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.16/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/CorsFilter.java#L692) method for more info.