# Access-Control-Allow-Origin by same domain?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server.chatcoding.net:8000/socket.io/
socket.io.js.
Origin http://www.chatcoding.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

That thing is preventing the socket script from loading. What happened here?
It's still on the same domain, but why is it emitting that error?

Anyone? Thank you. :)

Comment: It's not on the same domain, and not on the same port.

Answer (score 3):

You are on a same domain, but different ports (80 and 8000; [source](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)). the cross-domain policy is then applied. Try to setup your response header like that :

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if CORS is enabled on your server.
Refer to http://enable-cors.org/server.html for help on how to enable it.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a sub-domain issue. You'll need to check who is requesting your page and if they are allowed (such as any sub-domain), send the header.

I used this to answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737907/1215393

Comment: Thank you for that answer, but it seems that the problem has been fixed by creating a subdomain called server.www.chatcoding.net. Weird though.

Comment: @JoshuaLangit123 Woah. That's new.

Answer (score 0):

`server.chatcoding.net` and `www.chatcoding.net` are basically two different domains(but the subdomains are same).